# How can I switch around the content of a line of text

Tags: bash, sorting, edit

I have a large file (around 39,000 lines of text) that consists of the following:

```
1:iowemiowe093j4384d
2:98j238d92dd2d
3:98h2d078h78dbe0c
(continues in the same manner)
```

and I need to reverse the order of the two sections of the lines, so the output would be:

```
iowemiowe093j4384d:1
98j238d92dd2d:2
98h2d078h78dbe0c:3
```

Instead, I've tried using cut to do this but have not been able to get it to behave properly (this is in a bash environment), what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk -F: '{print $2":"$1}' input-file
```

Or

```
awk -F: '{print $2,$1}' OFS=: input-file
```

If you may have more than 2 fields:

```
awk -F: '{print $NF; for(i=NF-1; i; i-- ) print ":"$i }' input-file
```

Or

```
perl -F: -anE '$\=:; say reverse @F' input-file
```

or

```
perl -F: -anE 'say join( ':',  reverse @F)' input-file
```

( Both perl solutions are untested, and I believe flawed, each requiring a `chop $F[-1]` or similar to remove the newline in the input.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$2":"$1` to reverse the fields?

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -ri 's/([^:]+):(.*)/\2:\1/' file.txt
```

Results:

```
iowemiowe093j4384d:1
98j238d92dd2d:2
98h2d078h78dbe0c:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash and almost as fast as the awk solution from William Pursell, just not as elegant:

```
paste -d: <(cut -d: -f2 input-file) <(cut -d: -f1 input-file)
```